# How I can Add an extra 'status' field in auth_user Table in Django?

Tags: django, authentication, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms

I want to add 'status' field in my django auth_user table, Please let me know how i can add this field. I was trying to add by signup form but i am unable to migrate from there, I am getting error. 
Is there are any other option where i can add this field in Django default login functionality.

Comment: You probably then should customize the `User` model: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/#using-a-custom-user-model-when-starting-a-project

Comment: A form will not migrate the table since, well, a form has nothing to do with tables.

Comment: I an getting this type off errors...
`auth.User.groups: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'User.groups' clashes with reverse accessor for 'User.groups'.
`

Comment: I just user this for create status field in my auth_user table...
`from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser`
`class User(AbstractUser):
    status=models.BooleanField(default=True)
    USERNAME_FIELD='status'
`
Now i am getting some auth and permission errors on my terminal..

Comment: did you follow the entire tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

hey you will have to overide the you model.You can add multiple new column

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin, BaseModelMixin):
   status  = models.CharField(max_length=12)
```

and setting file you have to add the

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = "accounts.User"
```

Comment: What is "accounts.User"...Because i did not create anything with accounts

Comment: you will have to create the your own app, in which you will override the AbstractBaseUser

Answer (score 0):

You can inherith a model from AbstractBaseUser class. It provides the core implementation of a user model, including hashed passwords and tokenized password resets. According to the official documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model

```
class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    status= models.CharField(max_length=40)
    ...
```